# How to change Spinner's dividers color?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, divider

I Have integratad a `Spinner` in my application, now I want to change the dividers in the popup that opens when I click on the spinner from white to another color, I have added the following in my `styles.xml` as suggested here in one of the posts:

```
 <style name="applicationTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/mySpinnerStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="mySpinnerStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:divider">#00ff00</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">5dp</item>
</style>
```

and appliad the `applicationTheme` in the `Manifest` file like so:

```
  <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/applicationTheme" >  
    ...
```

But this didn't do me any good. Does some knows how can I change the dividers in the `Spinner`'s popup?

Thanks.

Comment: The item `android:dropDownListViewStyle` exists in your theme in the "versions" values-v11 and values-v14? Does this error happens in all android api levels?

Comment: Actually corrently I have only: values and values-large

Comment: This happens in landscape AND portrait mode? Are you using Actionbar Sherlock? Could you try to set the theme in the activity tag (on the manifest) just to see if works... ?

Comment: I have no landscape mode for this activity, I tried to set the style for the activity, and even added to it a typeface parameter to see that it's affects the activity but the divider has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Set the 
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" 
in your Spinner and it should work